# NestJs Guard that handles multiple Passport Strategies - is it possible?

Tags: session, cookies, jwt, nestjs, passport.js

So I'm developing an API using NestJS. Currently, my way of authenticating users is via Passport Local strategy. Simple enough. However, my app has a possible integration with 3rd party applications. Which means, others may create an app that would request data via my API. And the only reasonable way that I can think of, for them to be able to do so is via JWT. My question is, is there a way in NestJS for a guard to handle multiple strategies?

Say, I have this route: `GET https://www.myhost.com/api/employee`. If my first party application tries to access this route, the guard would look for a session `Cookie` from the request header. But, if a 3rd party application tries to send a request on the same route, the guard would look for bearer token inside `Authorization` header

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: Could you give me an example as to how you would have possibly implemented it, or perhaps point me to the docs if ever it was mentioned and I missed it out?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards  there is everything. Yours guard will just check two conditions and return true || false depending on them.